# Magento 2 - Insert Customer Vat Number in Invoice PDF

Tags: magento2, invoice, vat

My customer would like to deliver a complete PDF Invoice according to italian law.

- In every invoice should be indicated the **customer's vat number**.

Where and how can i insert this **variable**?

Comment: You can override this file /vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php  and call there the Customer Vat Number.

Comment: Check this stack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241663/magento-2-how-to-override-protected-funtion-in-abstract-class it is a reply to similar question.

Comment: I thank your for your kind answer, but I don't know how to do it